# Getting magic number error?

Tags: python

The error I am getting is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 391, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 385, in main
    find_rop_gadgets('libc.so')
  File "test.py", line 78, in find_rop_gadgets
    e = elf.ELF(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pwnlib/elf/__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
    super(ELF,self).__init__(self.mmap)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elftools/elf/elffile.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._identify_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elftools/elf/elffile.py", line 201, in _identify_file
    elf_assert(magic == b'\x7fELF', 'Magic number does not match')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elftools/common/utils.py", line 69, in elf_assert
    _assert_with_exception(cond, msg, ELFError)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elftools/common/utils.py", line 101, in _assert_with_exception
    raise exception_type(msg)
elftools.common.exceptions.ELFError: Magic number does not match
```

What is the magic number in python?What does the error in the above code means?

Comment: You really don't need to post the *whole program*. Please reduce this to a workable [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: MArtijn Pieters,I posted a question before with just the errors and many readers asked me to post the entire code for they can't be able to help me with just the errors.So I thought I should post the codes too.Can You help me with this?

Comment: You need to post the minimum amount to reproduce the issue, no more, no less. See [mcve]. Sorry, I can't help here.

Answer (score 1):

The ELF format (Executable and Linkable Format) is a common file format for binary code files such as dynamic libraries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

This message indicates that the file you're checking is not a valid ELF file format. ([Take a look at line 201 in the source code for elffile.py](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/blob/master/elftools/elf/elffile.py)). The code reads 4 bytes from the file and checks that they match the value `0x7fELF`:

```
elf_assert(magic == b'\x7fELF', 'Magic number does not match')
```

This 'magic number' is the start of an ELF format header. If these bytes are not a match, it's an indicator that the file is corrupted and/or not a valid ELF format file. You can use the `readelf` command to inspect the header of an ELF binary:

```
readelf -h file
```

From the stack trace that you posted, function `find_rop_gadgets('libc.so')` is looking at `libc.so`, which is passed to `elffile.py` for validation (where it fails validation because it isn't an ELF file). I think it's reasonable to inspect `libc.so` and make sure that the file exists and is a valid (uncorrupted) ELF file.

Without more specific information (i.e. a code example), this answer is about as specific as it can be.

See [this page for more details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) on the ELF file format.